# UICollectionView item size issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have set the item size in sizeForItemAtIndexPath method of flow layout as below

let itemSize = (self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 7)

return CGSizeMake(itemSize, itemSize)

But, it shows a pixel difference in between cells and that different varies between iPhone 5 and 6.

How to fix it ?

[image: The black lines shouldn't be there]

Comment: I can't really tell what's wrong with the screenshot. Can you highlight the issue?

Comment: you see those black lines in between the numbers in both of the sections? that is the issue. I can think like when I divide the view width by 7, those small pixels are left out because of cannot be added equally to those 7 portions of cells. please let me know if you need any thing or I didn't explain the issue clearly still.

Comment: oh i see now. Are you trying to get rid of those lines completely? I'd just set the collection view's background color to white, that's the easiest way to fix it =)

Comment: Yep, i dont want them. Yes, thats the easiest fix, but those white lines will show in between grey cells :)